# ServiceStack hosted in IIS - need hook to know when web service is shutting down

Tags: asp.net, iis, servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack 4.0.30319 hosted in IIS 7.

When the web service is shutting down or being recycled, I need some kind of notification so I can do some cleanup before it shuts down. (Yes, I understand that this notification wouldn't work if the web service crashes or is forcibly killed. But in the normal case I would like to shut things down in an orderly way when possible.)

Can anyone suggest how I can do that?

My AppHost inherits from AppHostBase. There are quite a few methods in AppHostBase that can be overriden to add special handling on various events, for example OnBeforeInit, OnAfterInit, etc. But there doesn't seem to be anything for when the web service shuts down.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ASP.NET Global.asax **Application_End** Event, e.g:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // Add Clean-up code here...
    }
}
```